# Account merge of a candidate nominee in an election hides the candidate

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

At this moment, we're having an election in [Portuguese Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1). The candidates are nominating themselves.

However, at this moment, the page shows that there are 7 candidates, but only 6 show up. The reason is probably because one of the candidates had two accounts and they have been recently merged, so they aren't showing up anymore in the list.

If the candidate was silently removed on purpose for some reason, the counter is still wrong anyway, so this is a bug nevertheless.

Comment: Can you be sure that a candidate has not withdrawn?  I think they can do that by deleting the answer they used to nominate.

Comment: @PolyGeo I really don't know. However, yesterday I wrote a comment in the candidate's nomination, which he answered with another comment, and his another comment still shows up in my inbox.

Comment: If I recall correctly, if a comment is a reply to you then it will remain in your inbox (at least for a while) when a post is deleted, as long as the comment itself is not. The same may apply to retracted nominations.

Comment: @Nick Well, I would be relief if this is just a bug in the counter. However, I'm afraid that something more fishy could be happening due to the account merge as this is something very corner-case. So, it is better to ask anyway and wait for an official answer on this.

Comment: There don't appear to be any withdrawn nominations, nor any merges on any of the nominees' accounts... grabbing a dev to have a look.

Comment: @VictorStafusa pointed me to the relevant user: it appears the counter is right, but the nomination isn't showing up due to a merge performed after the user nominated. Definitely need a dev to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I am the aforementioned candidate. My candidacy still stands, I didn't withdraw myself. The election page shows me an error page instead, now.

Comment: New status: I can now see the election section on Portuguese Stack Overflow, but I cannot see my nomination.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed. Issue is that the elections system didn't know how to handle a user merge of an active candidate (and then caching). The nomination count is now up to date and the [missing nomination](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/4#post-474472) is now showing up.

---

> nominate yourself
> user merge; oh no! post gone!
> dev intervention

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your time to address this.

Comment: `.replace('dev', 'divine');`

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask `status-bydesign`